# How to get Firebase InAppMessaging Instance ID programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Is there a way to get Firebase InApp Messaging programmatically?

```swift
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID {} // returns fcm token
Messaging.messaging().fcmToken // returns fcm token
```

We can get the InApp Messaging while enabling the debug mode argument, but I wonder if this is possible to get it programatically.

[Firebase InApp Messaging Docs: iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=2#get_your_apps_installation_id)

Answer (score 6):

You have to import `FirebaseInstallations` and call the following:

```
    Installations.installations().installationID { id, error in
        print("Id used to debug Firebase InApp Messaging: \(id)")
    }
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations)